# Azure Blob Container

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

I am new to Azure PowerShell scripting.

How can i check if a blob container exist under a storage account and create it if it does not exist.

I Tried the below code:

```
$StorageAccountName = "autodeploystorageacc1818"
$ContainerName = "acceleratorblobcontainer"
$ResourceGroupName =  "autodeploy"
$skuName = "Standard_LRS"
Try
{  
   Get-AzureRmContext -ErrorAction Continue  
}  
Catch [System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException]  
{  
   Login-AzureRmAccount  
}
Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName 
$StorageAccountName  = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $StorageAccountName
New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $ContainerName -Permission Off`
```

But how can this be written as a conditional statement any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you started by reading the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the container is already exist(or)not using `Get-AzureStorageContainer` command

```
## Get Parameters
Param(
    [string] $ResourceGroupName,
    [string] $StorageAccountName,
    [string] $StorageContainerName
)

## Static Parameters
#Login-AzureRmAccount
#Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionID 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
#$ResourceGroupName = "GroupName"
#$StorageAccountName = "AccountName"
#$StorageContainerName = "ContainerName"

$Keys = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName;

$StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $Keys[0].Value;

if (!(Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $StorageContext | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $StorageContainerName })){
New-AzureStorageContainer -Context $StorageContext -Name $StorageContainerName -Permission Container;  
}
 else {
Write-Warning "Container $StorageContainerName already exists."
}
```

Refer [here](https://prcode.blog/2017/06/05/azure-container-with-powershell/)

Comment: One problem that I see with the code above is that it lists all blob containers in a storage account to identify if a blob container by that name exists. Furthermore it will only list 1st 5000 blob containers (max blob container / request) so if there are more than 5000 blob containers and the list did not include the container name being created (but is present), above code will not go into the else block.

Comment: Thanks Jayendran Much Appreciated I will try this

Answer (score 1):

Kind of anti-pattern but you could wrap the call to create the container in a try/catch block and then catch exception to determine if the container exists.

```
$AccountName = "account name"
$AccountKey = "account key"
$StorageContainerName = "container name"
Try
{
     $ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $AccountName  -StorageAccountKey $AccountKey
     $container = New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $StorageContainerName -Context $ctx -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch
{
    Write-Warning "Container $StorageContainerName already exists."
}
```

The code to create a container can fail for various reasons so what you should do is capture the specific exception (`ResourceAlreadyExistException` in this case) and handle that specifically.

Answer (score 0):

No need of going through all the container details using Get-AzureStorageContainer, just handling the ResourceAlreadyExistException will do the work like below.

```
try {
    New-AzStorageContainer -Name $ContainerName -Permission 'Container' -Context $DestCtx -ErrorAction Stop
} catch [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common.ResourceAlreadyExistException] {
    Write-Output 'Container already exists'
}
```